# Proving least squares is a minima

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-regression

Minimizing $ f(\beta) = (Y-X\beta)'(Y-X\beta) $ we take the derivative set it to zero and get $ \beta = (X'X)^{-1}X'Y $ now everywhere I've read they say this is the minima because $ (X'X) $ is positive definite, if its full rank. Now why does that tell us this is a minima? Don't we need to retrieve the hessian matrix or something?

Answer (score 0):

The Hessian matrix is $2 X' X$.  But this is taking things slightly backwards.  The idea of the Hessian matrix is to approximate your function in the neighbourhood of the point in question by a quadratic form.  Here you already have a quadratic form to begin with.

One of the characterizations of positive definite is: an $n \times n$ real symmetric matrix $A$ is positive definite if and only if  $v^T A v > 0$ for all  $v \in \mathbb R^n$ except $0$.

Comment: So to get the hessian you took the second derivative with respect to the $ \beta $-vector right? So you are saying that by only looking at $ -2X'Y + 2X'X\beta $ we can say its a minima? How?